# How to use send keys when input='file' doesn't exist using Ruby and Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath

I'm working on a web scraper with Ruby and Selenium that will take a CSV file and import it into Google Sheets.

Everything is fine until I need to target the "select a file from your device" input and upload the file using send keys. Normally I see an `input='file'` tag and use that, however I'm no longer seeing it.

What I would do is

```
driver.find_element(xpath: '//*[@type="file"]').send_keys("#{Dir.pwd}/my_file.csv")
```

but this no longer works as there's no `type='file'`.

This is what I see when I inspect:

```
<div role="button" class="a-b-c d-u d-u-F" tabindex="0" style="user-select: none;">Select a file from your device</div>
```

Is there a different way I could do this without targeting an input with a type of "file"?

Comment: Is it possible to give the url of the website you are automating?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this XPath expression :

```
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait=10
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@class][contains(text(),'device')]")
element.click
element.send_keys "#{Dir.pwd}/my_file.csv", :enter
```